# make ODBC link work over VPN

Tags: vpn, remote-access, microsoft-access, odbc

I've created an Access file that contains ODBC links to our web-based ERP system, with a form full of graphs tracking various company metrics against target figures.
The Access file is stored on our company's shared drive, so it's accessible to everyone. It's a pretty constant work in progress as I'm often asked to add a section/graph or tweak the layout.

I need to get it working on the laptop of a user that works from home. He uses a VPN into the work network to access shared files, but if he tries to open this tracker file, Access stops responding on his laptop. It works fine when his computer is in the building (connected directly to the network rather than over VPN).

Is this a known issue? Any workarounds? I know it could be fixed by putting a local copy of the file on his machine and/or taking snapshots of the data from ODBC rather than constantly updating, but I'm reluctant to do either of those due to the very live and still-work-in-progress nature of the tool. Is there anything else I can do to allow it to load through a VPN?
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to get it working on the laptop of a user that works from home.
> He uses a VPN into the work network to access shared files.......   Is
> this a known issue? Any workarounds?

Pretty much yes.  Access and other database systems do not respond well to Client on VPN and DB on server. It is possible to damage the DB so I recommend you do not do this. Use a workaround instead (one posted).

Workaround: Set up an Office Desktop computer and have the remote user RDP into the Desktop computer to use Access (running on this Desktop).

This has worked in numerous circumstances for us.